# Fix program freeze with ram buffer

Tags: linux, freeze, cache

I'm using program with small bug. It's closed - source, so i cant change it code. It's very good for what its doing, and there is no apps like that one. So i can't use other programs.

But that program has very big problem - that is how she works with disk. It has 2 files - main file where it saves evrything, and backup of that file. That "small" bug - she makes backup byte by byte ( read byte - write byte ). And it does that very five minutes. I'm having SSD disk, and that should be a problem beacos that file is very small (6898 bytes). But , for some stupid reason it frezes when its saving. Its not just small 100 ms freeze, that is very big , 10 second freeze.

So i'm having question: can i do someting about it ? Can i maybe use buffers, or even ram disk (14 mb of memory isnt a problem at all). If i would do ram disk - i need to make sure that info in files are saved to actual disk. That information isnt that big , so if it will be rolled back for 5 minutes - its not that big a problem at all ( its saves it evry 5 minutes , so that really should be a problem at all).

So , question is: how can i speed it up, and what is better to do: buffer, cache, or maybe RAM disk?

And, just so you know: one of the biggest problems with it, there is more files in root folder - so it should be only that one folder if i would use RAM disk.

Comment: Doing this on a ramdisk should give you the maximum speed possible without modifying the program itself.

Comment: But will it autosave information to real disk?

Comment: No. If you set it up to save to the ramdisk, it won't save to the real disk. It'll save it to the ramdisk.